# Nuxt/Vue CORS error on change page, with asyncData

Tags: nuxt.js, asyncdata

I have an error on my Nuxt App and I don't understand why it not work. I have 2 files post_data.json and 0001.json in my server.
The post_data.json work without any CORS issue, this is the index.vue page fetch :

```
  async fetch() {

    const type = 'post';

    await this.$store.dispatch('getPostBy',type).then(()=> {
        console.log("Got some data, now lets show something in this component")
    }, error => {
        console.error("Got nothing from server. Prompt user to check internet connection and try again", error)
    })  
  },
```

in store :

```
 async getPostBy ({ commit, state}, type) {
        try {
          let siteUrl = state.api_url;
          let url = `${siteUrl}/${type}/${type}_list.json`;
    
          const headers = {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json",
          };
    
          await fetch(url, {
              method: "GET",
              headers,
          })
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(response=>{
              commit('SET_POSTS', response) // Save Item in Store
          })
          .catch( e=> {
              console.log("getPostBy 3. OUTSIDE 401 ", e);
          });
    
        } catch (e) {
        }
      },
```

Instead, when I navigate to single post, i get this error :

> Access to fetch at 'http://www.example.com/post/0001.json' from origin
> 'http://localhost:8010' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is the code of asyncData :

```
   asyncData({app, route, store}) {
    const id = route.query.p;
    const category = 'post';

try {

  let siteUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
  let url = `${siteUrl}/${category}/${id}.json`;


  const headers = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
  };

   fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      //mode: "no-cors",
      headers,
  })
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(response=>{
    console.log("response", response)   
    let item = response;
    
    store.dispatch("updateItem", {item})

  })
  .catch( e=> {
      console.log("asyncData error ", e);
  });

} catch (e) {
}
```

},

If i open the file in browser or if I reload the page, i will see the content of json file, instead if I change route I get the CORS error.
I tryed to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" and also mode: "no-cors", but i still have the issue.

Comment: Not sure why you do want to make an HTTP call to your own server rather than loading the JSON directly, the latency is kinda useless here. You don't get any CORS issue at first because the first page to be rendered is rendered on the server (where you don't have any CORS). I'm not sure if you want to keep this structure, there are several ways to hack CORS locally. Here, Nuxt and the "backend" are the same. Give a read [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnuxt%5D+cors), or a search engine will probably be able to tell you how to bypass it in a Node.js context (don't need to be Nuxt)

Comment: Thanks kissu, no i don't want to have that, i'm just trying to understand why that error. In production the url will be in https and also the CORS will be removed. 
I wanted to figure out if it was connected to nuxt or if it was something server related (although I set .htaccess with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*")

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong (thought it was local from local). CORS is always related to the server. The error (can be googled) is about the backend not whitelisting a specific frontend. It's a security concern, you need to say what is allowed. Here `http://www.example.com/` is not allowing your localhost to send any requests. So you should define in your backend, the URL of your Nuxt app. How/where is all depending of your backend. Feel free to search engine it!